# Why does explorer.exe open pdf files with Internet Explorer while Adobe Acrobat is registered?

Tags: excel, vba

Why does Explorer.exe open pdf's with Internet Explorer while Adobe Acrobat is registered to open pdf files?

This is the code line:

`Shell "Explorer.exe /n," & Chr(34) & strPathWithFileName & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus`

Is there a solution other than spesifically set the application for pdf's?

I use Windows XP and Excel 2007.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
ActiveWorkbook.FollowHyperlink strPathWithFileName
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below sub to open PDF file with Adobe reader. You must correct adobe reader and file path for `Windows XP`. See exact location of adobe reader then use that path.

```
Sub OpenPDF()
Dim AdobeReader As String
Dim MyFile As String

    AdobeReader = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC\Reader\AcroRd32.exe"
    MyFile = "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\PI_Adhesive_Sticker_SMI.pdf"

Shell AdobeReader & " " & MyFile, vbNormalFocus
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not I ask. I ask a solution with not seting an application spesifically in code.  Adobe Acrobat is the application which is registered to open pdf's in my OS but explorer.exe ignores this. Main idea is when this application is used another OS and application set, pdf's  are opened with whatever application is registered.